# Opening native applications within Electron?

Tags: electron

I have an Electron app and from within it I want to be able to open a native application (i.e Spotify) in a frame. I want to be able to control the layer and position of the window -- is this possible?

Here's a visual.

[image]

Comment: To me this does not seem possible. Not without a considerable amount of effort.

Comment: Bummer, that was my initial thought as well.